# How To Upload Images and Show Their Thumbnails From Custom Module Admin Form

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, media-images, crud

I have a custom grid. Need to upload product images from admin form of the custom module.

Here is the grid Edit file at:

> app\code\local\Crud\Banner\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Form.php

```
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('banner_form', array('legend'=>Mage::helper('banner')->__('Banner information')));

    $fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Title'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        //'required' => true,
        //'readonly' => true,
        'name' => 'title',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('filename', 'image', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Upload Banner'),
        'class' => 'required-entry',
        //'required' => true,
        //'readonly' => true,
        //'renderer' => 'banner/adminhtml_banner_renderer_image',
        'name' => 'filename',
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('status', 'select', array(
        'label' => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Status'),
        'name' => 'status',
        'values' => array(
            array(
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Desabilitado'),
            ),

            array(
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => Mage::helper('banner')->__('Habilitado'),
            ),
        ),
    ));

    if ( Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBannerData() )
    {
        $form->setValues(Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getBannerData());
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBannerData(null);
    } elseif ( Mage::registry('banner_data') ) {
        $form->setValues(Mage::registry('banner_data')->getData());
    }

    $this->setForm($form);

    return parent::_prepareForm();
}
```

> Here is the controller SaveAction:

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $bannerModel = Mage::getModel('banner/banner');

            $bannerModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
            ->setTitle($postData['title'])
            ->setStatus($postData['status'])
            ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBannerData(false);

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBannerData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the save controller with image save code, Check the below code

```
public function saveAction()
{
    if ( $this->getRequest()->getPost() ) {
        try {
            $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $bannerModel = Mage::getModel('banner/banner');

            if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name])) {
                try {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png')); // or pdf or anything
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . / ;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name']);
                    $postData['filename'] = $path.$_FILES['filename']['name'];
                }catch(Exception $e) {
                    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                }
            }

            $bannerModel->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'))
            ->setTitle($postData['title'])
            ->setStatus($postData['status'])
            ->setStatus($postData['filename'])
            ->save();

            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBannerData(false);

            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setBannerData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: For some reason it is not saving.